# How do I hide all columns and unhide specific columns based on user input?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement to display only the specific columns in an excel sheet. How do I hide all columns and unhide only the needed ones? Suggestions please.

```
worksheet.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = true
```

This doesn't work for me.

Comment: It wont that way.  Have you done any research? `cells.EntireColumn.Hidden=true`  your prefix `worksheet` is a type, so you'd want something like `sheets("sheet1")` or `activesheet` maybe,

Comment: ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Columns("c").Hidden = False      I tried this but I do get an error saying "Unable to get hidden property of the range class"

Comment: 1st one works ok for me.  Is your worksheet protected in anyway/

Comment: No, its not protected by anyway

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you already know what columns you want to hide, and on what worksheet.

Use this instead...

`Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(5).EntireColumn.Hidden = True`

Or

`Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you first need to unhide all columns:

```
ActiveSheet.Columns.Hidden = False
```

Next you want to hide specific column(s):

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ColumnToHide).Columns.Hidden = True
```

However! If you have merged cells in your worksheet this may fail since you can't hide part of a merged cell.